# Scroll the active div to left while page scroll after find the anchor id in navbar (Mobile View)

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need like in this example website in mobile view https://www.regus.com/en-gb/virtual-offices

In mobile view on page scroll (option, whats include) div set a fixed and overflow-x scroll

what i need is while page scroll it is find the anchor active section and move the sub nav title to center or move to left. so i need the solution for this.

i found this for onclick function

```
   $('classname').on('click',function(){

  var pos=$(this).position().left; //get left position of classname
  var currentscroll=$("classname").scrollLeft(); // get current scroll position
  var divwidth=$("classname").width(); //get div width
  pos=(pos+currentscroll)-(divwidth/3); // for center position if you want adjust then change this

  $('classname').animate({
            scrollLeft: pos
  });
});
```

but i need solution while page scrolling like in this site https://www.regus.com/en-gb/virtual-offices

Thanks In Advance.